# Check for Existing Computer in AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to check for an existing computer name in AD before renaming the local computer. Below is the code that I started with, but don't know why it's failing.

When I enter a computer name (MNBLAP) that I know is in AD, it jumps down to the         `else` statement. If I put in a computer name (RJKLAP) that I know doesn't exist, it throws an error.

```
$checkname = Get-ADComputer $newcomputername -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 if ($checkname -eq $newcomputername){
   Write-Host "The computer is already in AD."
  }
 else {
   Write-Host "The computer is not in AD."
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the error I receive

```
get-adcomputer : Cannot find an object with identity: 'RJKLAP' under: 'DC=domain,DC=domain'.
At C:\Scripts\CheckComputerName.ps1:25 char:14
+ ... checkname = get-adcomputer $newcomputername -ErrorAction SilentlyCont ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (RJKLAP:ADComputer) [Get-ADComputer], ADIdentityNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Cannot find an object with identity: 'RJKLAP' under: 'DC=domain,DC=domain'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.C 
ommands.GetADComputer
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your `if()` statement fails is that `Get-ADComputer` returns an `ADComputer` object, not just the computer name.

To trap the error in case the machine name *doesn't* exist, use `try`/`catch`:

```
try{
    $checkname = @(Get-ADComputer $newcomputername)
    if($checkname.Count -eq 1){
        # newcomputername found
        Write-Host "The computer is already in AD."
    }
}
catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException]{
    # newcomputername not found
    Write-Host "The computer is not in AD."    
}
```

Comment: Here's what I get if I pick something that wasn't found. If I pick something that would be found, it doesn't use the if or catch. 

Unable to find type [ADIdentityNotFoundException].
+     $checkname = Get-ADComputer $newcomputername
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ADIdentityNotFoundException:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

Comment: That fixed the issue regarding the error. Thank you so much. Now the only thing I'm having issues with is that when I enter MNBLAP as $newcomputername, it doesn't go to if(). I tried changing -eq to 0. If I put an else{} with a write-host, it appears there.